# How to print report more than once with difference invoice numbers

Tags: jasper-reports

Using *iReport 4.5.0*, I have designed the report to print invoice by giving the invoice no as parameter. The report contains *Title*, *Page header*, *Detail* (items in the bill), *Summary*, etc.

Every thing working fine. Now the client asking to print more than one invoice i.e from the list they will select more than one invoice and they want to print all?

Any idea? Do I need to change the entire report into detail section or any other idea

Comment: [Batch Export Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/batchexport/index.html#batchexport)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a few things.

You can keep the report as an individual report, and execute each report with a list of Invoice Numbers.  You will need to handle this in your application.

```
 where invoice.num = $P{invoicenum}
```

OR

Modify the report to be a batch report that takes in a list of Invoice Numbers.  To provide a list your application will need to generate a SQL appropriate list of invoice numbers/IDs what have you.

```
 where invoice.num in ($P!{invoicenums})
```

OR

Create a Batch Report that uses your Invoice report as a subreport, run a SQL query based on your criteria in the Batch Report, and use the Invoice Report as a detail band that gets passed Invoice Numbers.

Comment: right answer, although it would have been great if you'd explained '!' syntax difference.

Comment: Thank you. I am missed to add one important thing. I am not using any sql database connection in ireport, instead of that i am using java beans datasource and from java i am passing header with parameters and detail with java list

Comment: iReport 4.5.0 does have the option of creating batch report ? can you please link to any example ?